# Change the count of post views in fuction by random number

Tags: wordpress, post-meta

I have this function in a wordpress theme :

```php
// function to count views.
function setPostViews_anthemes($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

I need that the number of viws show a random number from 1 to 999

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random integer from `1` to `999` in PHP use `rand(1,999)`

```
// function to count views.
function setPostViews_anthemes($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = rand(1,999);   
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
```

Comment: So do I have to delete the original function and replace it ?